# How to block friend with xmpp in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I am working on the chat application. I want to block friend. I am using XEP-0016 extensions of xmpp framework.

Here is my code..

```
- (void)setupXMPPPrivacy
{
    NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] "), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    //Init XMPPPrivacy List
    //xmppPrivacy = [[XMPPPrivacy alloc] init];
    xmppPrivacy = [[XMPPPrivacy alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    //Activate xmpp modules
    [xmppPrivacy activate:xmppStream];
    //Delegate XMPPPrivacy
    [xmppPrivacy addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}


- (void)privacyBlock:(XMPPJID *)jid
{
    NSXMLElement *privacyElement = [XMPPPrivacy privacyItemWithType:@"jid" value:jid.bare action:@"deny" order:1];
    [XMPPPrivacy blockIQs:privacyElement];
    [XMPPPrivacy blockMessages:privacyElement];
    [XMPPPrivacy blockPresenceIn:privacyElement];
    [XMPPPrivacy blockPresenceOut:privacyElement]; 
    NSLog(@"-------> PRIVACY ELEMENT: %@", privacyElement);

    NSArray *arrayPrivacy = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:privacyElement, nil];
    [xmppPrivacy setListWithName:@"public" items:arrayPrivacy];
}
```

But, this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Help please. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding the delegate 2 times?

Comment: @Sunny did you solve your problem? I have same issue, so your help would be appreciated

Comment: @Zhans yes i had done but not through xmpp. i HAD MADE ONE WEBSERVICE THAT WILL MAINTAIN BLOCK LIST.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. First problem was UUID generator, it returned nil. But in iOS 5 added `NSUUID` class. So using `[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]` I solved this problem. Second problem was my big mistake. I initialized xmmpStram and did request to block, but opening stream takes some time.So, I requested before opening a stream.